# Good resource to learn more about background reduction CERN data analysis

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, data-analysis, large-hadron-collider

So I am working on a project which involves data analysis of LHCb data and I have to plot invariant mass histograms. Where can I learn more about background reduction in my analysis. I have to use mass of 2 other particles as backgrounds (I am using the PyROOT framework).

Comment: You can try the Cern Document Server http://cdsweb.cern.ch/